# Compute the least positive residue of $3^{83} \pmod {3600}$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Compute the least positive residue of $3^{83} \pmod {3600}$.

The group $\Bbb Z_{3600}$ is not cyclic. $3$ is not coprime to $3600$. So I did't know how to compute the congruence without calculator.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{3600}$ is not a group with respect to multiplication.

Comment: If you meant $\;\Bbb Z_{3600}=\Bbb Z/3600\Bbb Z\;$ , this it **is** cyclic (with respect to addition. With respect to multiplication it isn't even a group). Did you mean something else?

Comment: Translate into basic language if unsure - the least positive residue $r$ satisfies $3^{83}=3600n+r$. Now note that $r$ is divisible by $9$ so $r=9d$ and $3^{81}=400n+d$ - then you should be able to move forward.

Comment: Can you find $3^{83} \pmod{400}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the *Chinese remainder theorem*:
$$\mathbf Z/3600\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/16\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/9\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z/25\mathbf Z$$
and compute $3^{83}\mod 16, 9,25$

Note $3^2$, hence $3^{83}\equiv 0\mod 9$.

On the other hand(s), $3$ has order $4$ modulo $16$ and $25$, hence $\;3^{83}\equiv 3^3 \equiv\begin{cases}11&\bmod16,\\2&\bmod 25.\end{cases}$

There remains to solve the system of linear congruences
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv11\mod16,\\x\equiv2\mod25,\\x\equiv 0\mod 9,\end{cases}$$